# How to resolve force powers on minion groups?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-age-of-rebellion, star-wars-force-and-destiny

Minions groups acts as a single entity on Star Wars FFG.

But I'm not sure how force powers works with those groups of minions.

For example, my interpretation is that if I use a force power, like harm on its basic form, and target the group, the force power deals damage to the Wound thereshold of the combined group.

But...
What happens if I use the Force Power Harm with the Magnitude property against a minion group?

What happens if I use the Power Bind, on its basic form, against a group of minions?

What happens if I use the Force Power Move to target a single minion an throw it to another minion, and both minions are in the same group?

I guess the general question is. What are the rules of Force Powers and Minions?

Answer (score 1):

For Harm I'd go with damage to the group as a whole, potentially dropping more than one minion.

In the Move example you give I'd deal damage to both minions, but I would subtract soak for each of them separately rather than add damage first and then subtract soak once.

As far as Bind is concerned I advice letting it affect a single minion and merely split him off from the minion group, reducing their skill ranks as if a member of the group was disabled. If he is released later he can rejoin the group or act independently.

Basically, the rules for Force powers and minion groups is whatever the GM feels appropriate for the situation. They're only minions, which means they exist to let the PCs feel badass, so don't be afraid to let your players slap them around. If you feel they're having it too easy then use rivals instead.

Comment: Welcome to the site! We try to avoid "here's how I would rule" answers since they're pretty much just opinions, but your last paragraph could be turned into a great answer if you cite rules saying GMs should resolve Force powers on minions to make the PCs feel awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Bind logically only restrains one part of the minion group, so you have to suspend group rules, immobalize one target, and thus lowering the skill of the remaining group, unless you have the magnitude upgrade letting you immobalize enough targets to cover the entire group.

Harm explicitely harms one engaged living creature (and ignores soak), you would have to suspend group rules for this attack, too, and resolve it against individual foes. So with the Magnitude upgrade you can damage multiple foes in the group, but only disable them if your damage surpasses an individual foe's WT.
But since this sounds complicated to keep track of, I can imagine myself to allow a Character to simply multiply the damage and disable minions by the group rule normally, but that is merely convenience, not my word by word interpretation of the rules.

I don't see why Move wouldn't work just like any other ordinary attack against Minions. The rules state that if you want to hit multiple targets with one Move attack, you should apply autofire rules. I would simply allow to use the autofire rules against Minion groups as well, dealing damage by the silhouette of an individuum of course. The narrative then can explain this by throwing them at each other.

Maybe I overlooked a rule somewhere stating explicitely differently, but the Minion group rules are rules of convenience and as such I would always opt for the easiest interpretation.

Comment: The auto-fire rule does not apply to the question since it targets a single minion.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the rules of Force Powers and Minions?

The short answer is if you want to affect multiple minions, you would need to activate the magnitude upgrades unless your GM says otherwise.

Taking this into consideration:

> What happens if I use the Power Bind, on its basic form, against a
>   group of minions?

In its basic form, you restrain one minion. In this case, you immobilize temporarily one minion until the end of the next turn. This might affect the skill ranks as if a member of the group was absent.

> What happens if I use the Force Power Move to target a single minion
>   an throw it to another minion, and both minions are in the same group?

You harm both minions with equal damage. Similar to grenades where you can affect multiple targets, you deal damage to the **thrown minion** and the **target minion**. If the minions act as a group, the wound threshold is shared but each attack is soaked by armor.

> What happens if I use the Force Power Harm with the Magnitude property
>   against a minion group?

With the first magnitude upgrade, the remaining force point would harm an additional target. If you are targetting two minions, it would deal twice the damage to the group's wound threshold.

As a general answer, I recommend reviewing the current FAQ available in FFG site (v2.0, dated 11/20/2017). For additional examples on Minions groups, I recommend the developer's answered questions thread.

related to force powers and minions:
https://community.fantasyflightgames.com/topic/108101-ffg-developer-answered-questions/?do=findComment&comment=3207869

related to minions and Blast quality (as an example of damaging multiple minions in a group):
https://community.fantasyflightgames.com/topic/104222-official-answer-from-sam-on-how-minions-work-with-blasts/